Data Cloud IndividualId and Marketing Cloud SubscriberKey issue
We are using data cloud segmentaiton and activate it to Marekting cloud for CRM marketing purposes.
My question is if a client have multiple accounts (individualId), which individualid becomes a subscriberkey in marketing cloud?
For example,
Client Name: John has 3 accounts.
Individual Id:
2561234 (Main Id which includes DeviceId and other recent datas)
6545132 (Old Id, not used recently)
9864514 (Old Id, not used recently)
In this above case, I need IndividualId 2561234 to be a subscriberkey in marketing cloud so that all of the recent datas (purchase etc) could be integrated into Marketing Cloud Journey and take the planned decision split path.
However, recently I realized Individual Id 6545132 is activated to Marketing Cloud, and based on the help center, Data Cloud activates Individual Id randomly.
(Specific Individual Id cannot be picked to be activated into MC)
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_unified_profile_activation.htm&type=5
In this case, what should I do to retreive the main IndividualId 2561234 into MC?
Thank you

This is a really good and relevant question. I am curious to read the answer. That said, SFMC does not support individual ID as Subscriber Key. You would need to use either Lead, Contact or User ID for the cross cloud features to function as expected (e.g. tracking coming back to IER, or Salesforce Data Entry Events in Journey Builder)

@Lukas Lunow That said, SFMC does not support individual ID as Subscriber Key - sub key can be anything, no? Sure, some MC features expect contact ID et al but if you don't need those features...
